# SalesTax quickbooks online sdk

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbxml

I am trying to add an invoice via the sdk, but I get this message: "You have either selected a tax liability account on a transaction where it's not allowed, or
haven't specified a tax rate along with it." Here is my xml.

```
<InvoiceAdd>
<CustomerRef>
    <ListID>2</ListID>  
    <FullName>Adam West</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef>
    <ListID>54</ListID>
    <FullName>Accounts Receivable (A/R)</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<TxnDate>2013-04-22</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>1017</RefNumber>    
<TermsRef>
    <ListID>3</ListID>
    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
</TermsRef>
<DueDate>2013-05-22</DueDate>
<IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
    <ItemRef>
        <ListID>3</ListID>
        <FullName>Engine</FullName>
    </ItemRef>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity> 

    <Rate>500</Rate>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <IsTaxable>true</IsTaxable>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<InvoiceLineAdd>
    <Desc>TAX</Desc>
    <RatePercent>5</RatePercent>
    <Amount>25.00</Amount>  

    <IsTaxable>false</IsTaxable>
</InvoiceLineAdd>
<SalesTaxLineAdd>
    <RatePercent>5</RatePercent>
    <AccountRef>
        <ListID>59</ListID>
        <FullName>Batman's Payable</FullName>
    </AccountRef>
</SalesTaxLineAdd>
```

I created this xml from an invoice that I created in the gui.  I then did an Invoicerq and got this xml which I changed to the above xml.

```
<InvoiceRet>
<TxnID>34</TxnID>
<TimeCreated>2013-04-22T12:17:56</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2013-04-22T12:17:56</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>0</EditSequence>
<TxnNumber>34</TxnNumber>
<CustomerRef>
    <ListID>2</ListID>  
    <FullName>Adam West</FullName>
</CustomerRef>
<ARAccountRef>
    <ListID>54</ListID>
    <FullName>Accounts Receivable (A/R)</FullName>
</ARAccountRef>
<TxnDate>2013-04-22</TxnDate>
<RefNumber>1017</RefNumber>    
<TermsRef>
    <ListID>3</ListID>
    <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
</TermsRef>
<DueDate>2013-05-22</DueDate>
<Subtotal>525.00</Subtotal>
<SalesTaxPercentage>5</SalesTaxPercentage>
<SalesTaxTotal>25.00</SalesTaxTotal>  
<AppliedAmount>0.00</AppliedAmount>
<BalanceRemaining>525.00</BalanceRemaining>
<IsPaid>false</IsPaid>
<IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>
<InvoiceLineRet>
    <TxnLineID>1</TxnLineID>
    <ItemRef>
        <ListID>3</ListID>
        <FullName>Engine</FullName>
    </ItemRef>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity> 

    <Rate>500</Rate>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <IsTaxable>true</IsTaxable>
</InvoiceLineRet>
<InvoiceLineRet>
    <TxnLineID>2</TxnLineID>
    <Desc>TAX</Desc>
    <RatePercent>5</RatePercent>
    <Amount>25.00</Amount>  

    <IsTaxable>false</IsTaxable>
</InvoiceLineRet>
<SalesTaxLineRet>
    <RatePercent>5</RatePercent>
    <AccountRef>
        <ListID>59</ListID>
        <FullName>Batman's Payable</FullName>
    </AccountRef>
</SalesTaxLineRet>
```

If in the SalesTaxLineAdd tag I remove the AccountRef it creates an invoice with a saletax for the order called "Original Sales Tax."

I, however, want the tax rate that I created.  Why can I create an invoice using the tax rate but not through the xml?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using version 2 of the QuickBooks API. There is a limitation where you cannot set the tax code using the API so unfortunately you can't do anything about the "Original Sales Tax" that appears in QuickBooks Online.

According to Intuit, version 3 allows you to do this but it has only been released to a limited number of developers last week:

http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/04/quickbooks-api-v3-april-release.html